# QuantLibXL - Optionlet bootstrapping failure

Tags: options, quantlib, bootstrapping

I am trying to bootstrap the Optionlet volatility surface from a Cap/Floor volatility surface using QuantLibXL. To be specific, the data is from ICAP:

```
    STK  ATM   0  0.25  0.5  [...]
1Y  0.31 77.95    81.9  71.8
18M 0.34 83.08    89.2  76.6
2Y  0.37 86.03    96.2  80.1
[...]
```

Now, I can set up without errors `qlCapFloorVolTermSurface`, and `qlOptionletStripper1`, but when I trigger the actual computation, e.g., with `qlOptionletStripper1CapFloorVolatilities`, I get the error

```
qlOptionletStripper1CapFloorVolatilities - could not bootstrap optionlet
type: Put
strike: 25.000000 %
atm: 1.311340 %
price: 0.125286
annuity: 0.501145
expiry: March 22nd, 2017
error: root not bracketed f[0,24] -> [-1.3213e-002, -1]
```

I understand that the root searching algorithm cannot find a solution in  the specified range, but what can one do here *in practice?* Have I missed something?

**Additional info:**

- The optionlet stripper takes as argument an IborIndex, for which I am using an Euribor object with an `qlInterpolatedYieldCurve` on a composite yield curve called "(45) - Euro" in Bloomberg.
- Strangely, the ATM rate indicated in the output does not at all match what it should be, namely according to the optionletstripper1.cpp:

  atmOptionletRate_[i] = iborIndex_->fixing(optionletDates_[i]);

The fixing at March 22nd, 2017 retrieved with qlYieldTSZeroRate, is 0.60310%, not 1.311340%. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- All the indicated numbers as obtained from ICAP need to be divided by 100, as they are percentages
- The `OptionletStripper1` takes an IborIndex, which should have a tenor equal to 1Y. I had set it to 6M, and that seemed to cause problems

Ouch!